# Using a function that returns data in multiple places

Tags: typescript

**Edit**
It would be nice if `data` accepts something like this:

```
{
   error: boolean;
   errorText: string;
   ...anyOtherProperties
}
```

---

My use case here, is that I want to have a function that validate my form fields, but to that I need to pass my `data`, that has a unique `interface` bound to it and after that I need to return that modified `data`.
Here is an example:

```
const InvalidateAllFields = (error: unknown, data: UserInterface): UserInterface => {
    if (error instanceof z.ZodError) {
        const { fieldErrors } = error.flatten();
        for (const key of Object.keys(data)) {
            const indexKey = key as keyof UserInterface;
            const error = fieldErrors[indexKey];
            data[indexKey].error = !!error;
            data[indexKey].errorText = error?.[0] ?? '';
        }
    }
    return data;
};
```

Because of the `UserInterface` I can't really use it in another form, only the ones with that interface.

What would I need to do to use the same function in multiple places?

Comment: Change the type of `data`... ?

Comment: Generics `<T>(error: unknown, data: T): T`, assuming `InterfaceUnion` is common?

Comment: @crashmstr I didn't mean to upload `InterfaceUnion`, I use the `keyof` only to get available key to modify `data`.
I will look into generics

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Thanks to @crashmstr I did some research and found the answer for my problem.

Using generics was the way to solve this one.

First declare a type that can receive your generic and parse the keys correctly:

```
type DataType<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: { error: boolean; message: string };
};
```

Then when declaring the function, the important part is extending your `DataType` to the generic and then using the generic as the `data` and `return` type.

```
export const genericValidationFunc = <T extends DataType<T>>(
    errors: Record<string, { error: boolean; message: string }>,
    data: T
): T => {
    for (const key of Object.keys(data)) {
        const indexKey = key as keyof T;
        data[indexKey].error = !!errors[key]?.error;
        data[indexKey].message = errors[key]?.message ?? '';
    }

    return data;
};
```

And now when you call it to use in whatever place it may be needed it'll only point out if you are missing what is required in `DataType`, anything else is ignored.

e.g.

```
interface DataInterface {
    mydata: { text: ''; error: boolean; message: string };
}

let data: DataInterface = {
    mydata: { text: '', error: false, message: '' }
};


const errors = {
    mydata: { error: true, message: 'Hello World' }
};

// Now this doesn't give a warning, even though text is not 
//defined on my function as one of the returned values
data = genericValidationFunc <DataInterface>(errors, data);
```

PS. Although I tested it, and it worked for my use case, there may still be a problem within this code since I'm still learning typescript.